# PHP - Change MS Word special characters (^l , ^p , ^s) to ","

Tags: php, ms-word

So what I have is a MS Word docx file that contains some data which is not really sorted really nice.

/example output

1.
Lastname, Firstname

Address, City, State Zip

By doing Ctrl+Shift+* I can view all the special characters that exists within the file.

( ¶, ˚ , etc...)

then replace them with a "," to act as a separator then export the file on an excel format.

Would there be a way to replace this symbols using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been flogged many times here .. am only responding because yours have a little twist.

What you need to do is remove all the characters you don't want , then replace all spaces " " with ","

Removing none ASII Characters (3 Examples)

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]]/', '',$string);
```

Removing UTF8 Characters

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/u', '', $string);
```

Removing Line Feeds , Carriage Returns and Tabs

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/u', '', $string);
```

Replacing " " with  "," ;

```
$string = str_replace(" ",",",$string);
$string = trim($string,",");
```

You have more than enough options now  ..

I hope this helps

Thanks
:)

Comment: One of them would definitely work ... Keep me updated if it works or not

Comment: feedback: ok so tried the codes that you posted thank you very much... first code doesnt separate the columns that i need, second is almost the same and prints out my data on a straight row. last puts each letter on a column

Comment: Is it possible to have a sample of your data and what you want as possible out come ????

Comment: Thank you data looks something like this http://zephyrstorage.webs.com/examplecode.PNG the output that I would like to have is this data be stored on a spreadsheet /example/ 1 | Firstname | Lastname | Address | State | City/Zip | Phone

Comment: Then your title is wrong ... Update your question ... i would update my code and that should solve your problem .. have the format in doc intend of PNG would be nice to .. since that is what you are using

Comment: If you save the document as plain text form Microsoft Word (File -> Save As).. it would remove all the special characters .. it would only remain parsing the file ..

Comment: i think the title is right since the code that im using is already working, I just really need this specific symbols be replace automatically instead of using Find+Replace commands in MS Word http://zephyrstorage.webs.com/sampledoc.docx saving it as plain text, removes my capability to align the text to their respective columns

Comment: are you trying to work with word directly with php ??? or export it to text format and parse it ???

Comment: saving it has txt would give you this format  http://tidypub.org/glfeF with no special characters

Comment: The php code that i have, allows me to upload the Word file, export it to excel. but before I can have a good result where I have the data be sorted on the excel file. I need to replace this characters manually from the MS WORD file using CTRL+ SHIFT + * then replacing the symbols manually, I dont want it to be exported to a text format  since the result that I need should be on an excel format

Comment: can put the code here .. then we can update it to remove those characters